# How to get text value by span using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, typescript

I want to get text value `"user detail - 205 users"` by the span , but i can not change the code by adding id or class , can i use javascript to get this ?

```
<span style="color: rgb(0, 189, 12);">"user detail - 205 users"</span>
```

Comment: is the span inside a div that does have a class or id... you need to pull it into js somehow... which means you need dom access... which means class or id... so look higher in the html tree for that. and you would have to filter down to the span element children - and you may need to do some fancy filtering if it's a complicated structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the text "user detail" always exists you can find the span that includes that text and get the full text once found

```js
const spans = [...document.querySelectorAll('span')],
      wantedSpan = spans.find(el => el.textContent.includes('user detail')),
      wantedText = wantedSpan ? wantedSpan.textContent : 'Not Found';

console.log('wantedText:', wantedText)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span style="color: rgb(0, 189, 12);">"user detail - 205 users"</span>
```